# How to delete lines between the pattern but keep the line with the second pattern

Tags: sed

I would like to delete the lines between two patterns but keep the line from the second pattern. For example for the file using `MATER /  4401001     302` and `/` as a pattern:

```
$#         IDMAT   MATYP             RHO   ISINT    ISHG  ISTRAT   IFROZ
MATER /  4401001     302                       0       0       0        
$# BLANK                                                     QVM           IDMPD
                                                                               0
$#                                                                         TITLE
NAME PLINK Material                                                             
$#  SLFACM     FSNVL    DELTNL     STNOR     STTAN     IFLGC     BLANK    TLSTIF
       0.1                                                 0                    
$#   I3DOF    TOLCOR     IDRUP
         0        1.         0




$---+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8
$#         IDMAT   MATYP             RHO   ISINT    ISHG  ISTRAT   IFROZ
MATER /  4401005     103        2.753E-6       0       4
```

I would like to get:

```
$#         IDMAT   MATYP             RHO   ISINT    ISHG  ISTRAT   IFROZ
MATER /  4401005     103        2.753E-6       0       4
```

I tried to do it using the following piece of code:

```
awk 'BEGIN{p=1} /MATER \/  4401001/ {p=0} /\// {p=1} p' llink1.inc > llink2.inc
```

But it doesn't work on my CentOS - the both files `llink1.inc`  and `llink2.inc` are identical.

Could you help. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `awk` is possible, this can be a way:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{p=1} /line 1/ {p=0} /line 2/ {p=1} p' file
bla bla
line 2 
bla bla 
bla bla
```

It is a matter of using the `p` print flag, unsetting it when `line 1` is found and setting it again when `line 2` appears.

---

To make sure the lines we are printing are the correct ones, say:

```
$ cat a
1bla bla
line 1
2bla bla  
3gov gov 
line 2 
4bla bla 
5bla bla

$ awk 'BEGIN{p=1} /line 1/ {p=0} /line 2/ {p=1} p' a
1bla bla
line 2 
4bla bla 
5bla bla
```

---

Given your new sample input, this works to me:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{p=1} /MATER \/  4401001/ {p=0; next} /\// {p=1} p' file
$#         IDMAT   MATYP             RHO   ISINT    ISHG  ISTRAT   IFROZ
MATER /  4401005     103        2.753E-6       0       4
```

Comment: Good to read that, @Drago :) Note you can accept the answer if your problem is solved.

Comment: could you add some remarks how to use the code if in the pattern you have some special characters ... for example /. Thank you again

Comment: @Drago for that you need to escape the `/`. For example `awk 'BEGIN{p=1} /.\/line 1/ {p=0} /line 2/ {p=1} p' file` would make it it the starting line is `./line 1`.

Comment: I have this piece of text in the file of interest (llink.inc):
`aa
MATER /  4401001     302                       0       0       $#         IDMAT   MATYP             RHO   ISINT    ISHG  ISTRAT   IFROZ
MATER /  4401005     103        2.753E-6       0       4                
`
after applying:
`awk 'BEGIN{p=1} /MATER \/  4401001/ {p=0} /\// {p=1} p' llink1.inc > llink2.inc`
I don't see any difference between llink1.inc and llink2.inc ... could you help further. I would expect this:
`aa
MATER /  4401005     103        2.753E-6       0       4                
`
Thank you.

Comment: @Drago Please update your question with this sample input. In comments it is not possible to see the new lines.

Comment: What I see, @Drago is that you should look for a pattern to "stop" the printing. I tried "2nd column being `/`" but it does not work, as the second line has also a `/` in 2nd position. Is `4401005` fixed or may vary?

Comment: it may vary. The first pattern is fixed. The code should delete all the line till the next line with `/` comes.

Comment: @Drago ok, see my updated answer. It checks for the 2nd `/` appearing.

Answer (score 5):

your **sed** line is close:

```
sed '/line 1/,/line 2/{/line 2/!d}' file
```

test

```
kent$ echo "bla bla
line 1
bla bla  
gov gov 
line 2 
bla bla 
bla bla"|sed '/line 1/,/line 2/{/line 2/!d}'   
bla bla
line 2 
bla bla 
bla bla
```

same idea with **awk**: (works for the example in question)

```
awk '/line 1/,/line 2/{if(!/line 2/)next}7' file
```

same example:

```
kent$ (master|✚9) echo "bla bla
line 1
bla bla  
gov gov 
line 2 
bla bla 
bla bla"|awk '/line 1/,/line 2/{if(!/line 2/)next}7'
bla bla
line 2 
bla bla 
bla bla
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting error with this:

sed '/line 1/,/line 2/{/line 2/!d}' file

in CentOS:
 
d: Event not found.

Comment: with this awk code I am also getting error: 

/line: Event not found.

Comment: are you sure you ran it under bash? @Drago it seems that the `!` was expanded by your shell, which it shouldn't be.

Comment: `> echo $0`
`> /bin/tsh`

Comment: try to escape the `!` then, @Drago. or use bash.

Comment: I would like to stay in the tcsh because all my aliases will be lost if I change to bash. Thank you

Comment: @Drago cp your alias to bashrc isn't that hard, is it?

Comment: you are principally right - the script is running in bash. The problem is however this should work not only for me but for the customer too. And it will be difficult to persuade big amount of users to change their shell

Answer (score 0):

A short `awk`

```
awk '/line 1/ {f=1} /line 2/ {f=0} !f' file
bla bla
line 2
bla bla
bla bla
```

---

Even shorter, but not robust.

```
awk '/line/ {f=!f} !f' file
```

Comment: I am getting here error too:
f: Event not found.
@Jotne ... do you have an idea about the origin of the problem. Thank you

Comment: I do not see why this does not work, works fine in my Ubuntu 12.10. What OS are you on?

Comment: I am using CentOS 6.4 with tsh. Thank you

Comment: This should work, since its standard commands, try `gawk` or `mawk`, it may help.

Comment: awk/gawk are bot available in my tcsh but it will issue the same problem, mawk is not available

Comment: @Drago I have little experience wit  with `chts`, could you try `bash`?