# sed delete lines between two patterns, without the second pattern, including the first pattern

Tags: design-patterns, sed

my input file looks like this:

```
[1234]
text 
text
text

[3456]
text 
text
text

[7458]
text 
text
text
```

I want to delete all lines between the patterns, including FROM_HERE and excluding TO_HERE.

```
sed '/FROM_HERE/,/TO_HERE/{//p;d;}'
```

Now i have:

```
sed '/^\['"3456"'\]/,/^\[.*\]/{//p;d;}'
```

but this command does not delete the line FROM_HERE too. for 3456 at the end the input file should look like:

```
[1234]
text 
text
text

[7458]
text 
text
text
```

How can i achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: delete all lines from `[3456]`(including) to `[7458]` ?

Comment: no it does not. i have updated my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed or awk deleting lines between pattern matches, excluding the second token's line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177772/sed-or-awk-deleting-lines-between-pattern-matches-excluding-the-second-tokens) [How to delete lines between the pattern but keep the line with the second pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655694/how-to-delete-lines-between-the-pattern-but-keep-the-line-with-the-second-patter)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How, using sed, can one extract a regex-delimited range except for the last line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036889/how-using-sed-can-one-extract-a-regex-delimited-range-except-for-the-last-line)

Answer (score 3):

You could delete lines from your pattern to next blank line:

```
sed '/^\['"3456"'\]/,/^$/{d;}' file
```

Comment: `sed: -e expression #1, char 28: unterminated address regex` I got this error.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the lines starting from pattern `[3456]` till encountering the pattern `[7458]`(excluding the line with ending pattern) use the following command:

```
sed '/^\[3456\]/,/\[7458\]/{/\[7458\]/b;d;}' testfile
```

---

`/\[7458\]/b` - `b` command here is used to skip the line containing the pattern `\[7458\]`

`d` command is to delete a line
The output:

```
[1234]
text 
text
text

[7458]
text 
text
text
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Branching-and-flow-control

Answer (score 1):

Note: For the sake of the example I will only match 3456 and 7458 (and not "exactly [3456]")

You could do something like:

```
~$ cat t
[1234]
text1
text1
text1

[3456]
text2
text2
text2

[7458]
text3
text3
text3

~$ sed '/3456/,/7458/{/7458/!d}' t
[1234]
text1
text1
text1

[7458]
text3
text3
text3
```

That is: between FROM_HERE and TO_HERE (`/3456/,/7458/`) do the following: delete if it doesn't match TO_HERE (`{/7458/!d}`)